# Trying to validate date entry with javascript regex as the user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, date

I'm trying to update an older app with some date validation **as the user types** it in a text field.

I have a bare bones demo here http://jsfiddle.net/7d82j0ky/2/ where if you enter the following dates:

- 05/24/1972 (valid)
- 05/24/2020 (invalid year in this case, current year is where we max out at)
- 05/32/1972 (invalid day in this case)

The regex works, but it isn't valid until you enter the full date format of MM/DD/YYYY.  If you open the browser console you'll see it console out messages as you type.

I want the validation **as the user types, so per character** and if there is an invalid character, I want to prevent the default behavior of that invalid character so it is never added, so:

- 05/24 would be OK as you type
- 05/32 would not be OK, the two should not appear in the UI by preventing the default behavior of that key event, so you'd only see "05/3" in the text field as you type
- 0a would not be OK, like above the "a" should be prevented so you'd only see "0" in the text field as you type.

What's the best way to match the regex as you type along?

I have some test cases for the date regex here https://regex101.com/r/M8habw/1/ and they all seem to be working fine based on the dates we care about in the app. I'm not super adept at regex, but this one wasn't that difficult.

Here's the jsfiddle code to satisfy posting here:

```
<input class="input" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"/>

$('.input').on('input', function(e) {
    var regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/((19[2-9]\d{1})|20[0|1]\d{1})$/g;

    if (!this.value.match(regex)) {
        console.log('nope');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        console.log('yep');
    }
});
```

Comment: Try `var regex = /^(?:0[1-9]?|1[0-2]?)(?:\/(?:(?:0[1-9]?|1\d?|2\d?|3[01]?)(?:\/(?:1(?:9(?:[2-9]\d?)?)?|2(?:0(?:[01]\d?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/;` and use it with `RegExp#test`: `if (!regex.test(this.value)) {`

Comment: There are many questions already on how to validate a date. A regular expression is not particularly suitable for what you're trying to do, other approaches are simpler and more maintainable. Also, you can't validate the day part until you have the month and year.

Comment: I'm with @RobG. Dynamic type validation will just throw a bunch of errors before the user has finished typing-- bad UX. Maybe consider using a datepicker (like the one from jQuery), and then validate when the date is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot validate a date with only a regex. Or not a reasonable one at least. For it to take into account leap years etc. would be pretty advanced.

You can do that with a bit more javascript though. In your oninput function you can strip the non-digit characters, work with your string of digits (make sure it's a correct date) and only add the other characters (the "formatting characters") back  where they are supposed to be after that.

If you have a partial date in the format `MMDDYYYY` (but with potentially only some characters being filled out) and you want to ensure that this cannot produce an invalid date, you could have a function like below.
One trick is that creating an invalid date in Javascript will not always yield an invalid result, it will just overflow, so `2019-01-32` will give you the date for `2019-02-01`. While useful in some cases, it is annoying for us as we are trying to detect invalid dates. But we can then make sure the string representing the generated date is the same as the one we provided. If it is different, we are in the "overflow" case.

```
function hasErrors(val) {
    let month = val.slice(0, 2);
    let day = val.slice(2, 4);
    let year = val.slice(4);
    // The string is fully empty - not an invalid input
    if (!month.length) {
        return false;
    }
    // Only one of the months digits is filled out. Assume the rest will be filled out by the smallest possible valid value
    //   (optimistic heuristic)
    if (month.length === 1) {
        month += month === '0' ? '1' : '0';
    }
    // Invalid month
    if (+month > 12 || +month <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    // Month valid but day not filled - ok
    if (!day.length) {
        return false;
    }
    // Only part of the day filled, same as above with the month
    if (day.length === 1) {
        day += day === '0' ? '1' : '0';
    }
    // Days always invalid
    if (+day > 31 || +day <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    // If the year is not fully filled out, use any year with a 29 Feb
    if (year.length < 4) {
        year = '1972';
    }
    // Make sure the date is valid (e.g. no 31st of April)
    let sourceStr = [year, month, day].join('-');
    let date = new Date(sourceStr);
    if (!+date || date.toISOString().slice(0, 10) !== sourceStr) {
        return true;
    }

    // No error was detected
    return false;
}
```

Here is an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gtayv5s/).

Now as the others mentioned, UX-wise it is a pretty bad idea to block user input. This makes things confusing, especially when trying to edit the middle of the string rather than the end. A better solution would be to just indicate the error through styling. Here is an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjsm2oc5/) not blocking user input (just changed the part around line 76).